# How to set the input value of Reactive Form in html using angular

Tags: angular

I am implementing Shopping Cart using angular. Based on the number of times user clicks the add to cart button i want to set the value of the input field i.e quantity field to the number of times the user clicks the add to card button.

I am using reactive form for this. How this can be done? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qarnso

I tried setting the value by [value]="item.quantity" not getting the result.

```
<form [formGroup]="cartForm">
        <div formGroupName="quantity">
<table class="uk-table">
    <caption></caption>
    <tbody>
        <th class="uk-margin-left uk-width-large@m">Total Items: {{ cartItems.length }}</th>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div *ngIf="cartItems?.length > 0">
                    <div class="uk-margin" uk-grid>
                        <div *ngFor="let item of cartItems" class="uk-card-media-bottom uk-cover-container">
                            <img [src]="item.productImageUrl" alt="{{ item.productName }}"
                                class="uk-margin-xlarge-left uk-margin-medium-top">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>

                        <div *ngFor="let item of cartItems">
                            <div class="uk-card-body">
                                <h3 class="uk-card-title">{{ item.productName }}</h3>
                                <p>{{ item.productDesc }}</p>
                                <p>Price: {{ item.productPrice}}</p>
                                <div class="uk-width-1-3@s">
                                    Quantity: <input class="uk-input uk-margin-top" type="number"
                                     name="quantity"   formControlName="qty" [value]="item.productQty"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="uk-margin">
                                    <p class="uk-text-success">Available Stock Item: {{ item.productQty }}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <p>Total: {{ cartForm.value | json }}</p>
                        </div>




            </td>
            <td>


            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</form>

initForm() {

  this.cartForm = new FormGroup({
    quantity: new FormGroup({ qty: new FormControl() })
 });

 addToCart(product: Product) {
     const addedProducts = this._cartItem.find(el => el.id === product.id)
     console.log('Added Products', addedProducts);
     if(addedProducts) {

       addedProducts.productQty++;
       console.log('Quantity Products:', addedProducts.productQty);
     }
     else {
     this._cartItem.push({
       id: product.id,
       productName: product.productName,
       productDesc: product.productDesc,
       productPrice: product.productPrice,
       productQty: product.productQty,
       productImageUrl: product.productImageUrl
     });
    }

     /* console.log('Cart Item:', this._cartItem); */

     setTimeout(()=> {
       localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(this._cartItem));
       this.calculateProducts();
     },1000);

   }
```

The reactive form input field should have the value based on the number of times the user clicks in add to cart.

Comment: The source of truth is the **model**, not the view. Get your form control and set its value, and the view will be updated accordingly.

Comment: From where you call "addToCart" in your html?

Comment: the addToCart function code is in my service file.

Comment: @JBNizet can you please give me an example?

Comment: I recreated your scenario [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jo7btv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: @robert, thank you. But my addtocart button is in different component so from there I need to set the value so in that case how it can be done?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qarnso

Comment: @divyadave check this [fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwawo5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcart%2Fcart.component.html).

Comment: @robert Thank you it worked. I want to display total also dynamically then in this case how can i display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the total use something like this:

```
  getTotal(): number {
    let total = 0;
    (this.cartForm.get('items') as FormArray).controls.forEach(
      (fg: FormGroup) => {
        total += fg.controls.qty.value;
      }
    );
    return total;
  }
```

In your html:

```
<p>Total: {{ getTotal() }}</p>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwawo5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcart%2Fcart.component.html)

**UPDATE**

For max validation, you can add this inside **createItem** method:

```
qty: [product.productQty, Validators.max(product.productQty)]
```

Now validation is in place. If you enter more then productQty your form will become invalid. To verify this, add the following in your html:

```
Form Valid: {{ cartForm.valid }}
```

However this is a global error. To get a local one for each field add this method to **cart.component.ts**:

```
  getValidity(index: number): boolean {
    return (<FormArray>this.cartForm.get('items')).controls[index].invalid;
  }
```

And this html under the input field for quantity:

```
<div *ngIf="getValidity(i)">Too many</div>
```

Updated [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4vihmx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcart%2Fcart.component.html).

**UPDATE 2nd**

To delete an item from a FormArray you can use this short method:

```
  deleteItemFromTheCart(index: number): void {
    console.log('delete item from the cart at: ', index);
    (<FormArray>this.cartForm.get('items')).removeAt(index);
  }
```

in html add this line:

```
<button (click)="deleteItemFromTheCart(i)">Delete</button>
```

New [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-acjrch?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcart%2Fcart.component.ts).

Comment: On fork it is working fine. But on my actual project I am getting error as No value accessor for form control with path: 'items -> 0 -> price'

Comment: @divyadave check for these attributes in html: `formArrayName="items"`, `[formGroupName]="i"` also check for ReactiveFormsModule imports. Also 'price' is a new field? Part of the form?

Comment: Thanks there was some issue in cache problem solved:)

Comment: i want to add validator on the quantity so in this case I won't be able to add validators.max right?

Comment: I didn't received any error message I just wanted to add  validator on the input field so that quantity shouldn't go above the given limit that's why.

Comment: I want to delete the particular item from the cart, so trying items.controls.removeAt(item) but not working is it a correct way?